# How Can I setup Subdomains un

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to setup WordPress multi site on my ubuntu 10.04 laptop with apache2.

For normal WordPress installs in create an entry in the /etc/hosts file and create virtual hosts entry in /etc/apace2/sites-available directory and then soft link it to sites-enabled directory.
For sub domains, I added the server alias directive. But that is not doing anything. Do I have a syntax error. Please advice.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com *.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /home/myhome/Sites/public_html/mysite.com
#if using awstats
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
#we want specific log file for this server
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must restart or reload Apache after making changes to your Apache configuration file. What does it tell you when you run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Does it show you any error messages? That will tell you if you have a syntax error. For your reference, here is an example of using `ServerAlias` that I have on my own server. Note the difference between mine and yours. Maybe you should remove the initial `mysite.com` part and just leave `*.mysite.com`?

Let me know if that helps.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin jesse@domain.com
   ServerAlias www.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
   ServerName domain.com
   ErrorLog /var/log/domain.com-error_log
   CustomLog /var/log/domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @Jesse Bunch : restarting apache gives the following warning: `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts` .  I removed mysite.com and changed *.mysite.com to www.mysite.com.  Not even that is working. Very confused.

Comment: Can you post your entire httpd.conf file?

Comment: @Jesse Bunch : Apache on Ubuntu does not rely on httpd.conf.  It uses apache2.conf which includes httpd.conf and everything in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.  You are supposed to setup virtual hosts in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory and then create a soft link to them in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled direcory.  The httpd.conf file is blank on my machine. Here is the apache2.conf file: [link]http://pastebin.com/0TjKYxx1[/link] . I created file called mysite.com.conf which pasted in my first post.

Comment: (sorry could not fit everything in one comment)          This file is in sites-available and it has soft link in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled .  And it is being read by apache since http://mysite.com work.  Just the domain name does not.

Comment: So mysite.com works but whatever.mysite.com doesn't? Did you add the appropriate A record to your DNS configuration for whatever.mysite.com?

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: I don't understand, I have limited knowledge when it comes to network administration.  This is a site I am trying to build on my laptop.  I have an entry for mysite.com in my /etc/hosts file.  Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to confuse you. You'll need to add a line in your /etc/hosts file for each of your subdomains. Also, be sure you clear your DNS cache each time you add a new hosts file entry. I assume you have that covered since you have done it before.

Comment: On another note, there is an application like what we use on Mac that will configure all of this for you when you're developing locally. You should check it out: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

Comment: @Jesse Bunch:  Thank you www.mysite.com is working.  Does the hosts file accept wild cards like the apache virtual hosts files do?

Comment: They do not. Unfortunately, you're going to have to add a line to your hosts file for every domain. Glad you got it working!